# Get Client DateTime in Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a Servlet that uses a method from my DAO class. The respective method in turn requires 'Client' Date Time as its parameter.As the webapp will be used globally.

This Servlet gets called when user clicks a link from the sidebar menu. The 'sidebar_menu.jsp' is itslef a jsp page which I have included in my every view (<%@ include file = "url" >).

How can I pass the client datetime in the Servlet directly ?

Currently what I have done is: I am checking everytime if a request has 'datetime' parameter in the servlet. If not, then redirecting to the view.
My view again checks if there is a 'datetime' parameter before loading (inside onready). If not, then it appends the request with a client's datetime in the 'datetime' parameter and sends it to the specific servlet.

But so much redirects is making the page to load very slow.

Comment: I don't really understand. If the servlet needs a datetime as parameter, and the servlet is invoked when clicking a link, then why doesn't the link send the datetime as parameter directly?

Comment: How can I  generate a link with a datetime parameter at the time the user clicks it ?

Comment: Using JavaScript. But, how can you get the client datetime without JavaScript in your current solution?

Comment: I can do that, appending the link with datetime parameter using onclick. But that will cause to open the link with same datetime when the user reloads the page. Is there any other way ?

Comment: You could use JavaScript to send an AJAX request to your servlet every time the page loads.

Comment: Do you mean when my page is reload ?

Comment: loads, or reloads. That doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Can't get you, will it not create a loop ?  Servlet -> Page (while loading) ->Servlet -> ...

Comment: No. What I mean is that the link can just load a page (without calling your servlet), which would immediately send an AJAX request to the servlet, and update the DOM of the page.

Comment: Yes, we can do that way, Thanks @JBNizet